# wfs layer is displaying in ol3 but not in openlayers 2

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, geoext

I am working in openlayers 2.
I want to diaplay wfs layer in openlayers 2.
But it is not displaying.
When i tried the same in ol3 it is working fine.
But my whole project is in openlayers 2. So i want wfs layer in ol2.
Below is my code in both ol3 and ol2.
Please tell me where i am doing mistake

**OL3**

```
 <script>
        var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();


  var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
   loader: function (extent) {
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wfs/ows', {
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.1.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typename: 'AMBALA_sma',
            srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
            bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
    });
},

strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: sourceWFS
  });

var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
controls: [],
interactions: [

    new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
    new ol.interaction.DragPan()
],
layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
           // url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-d}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
           // opaque: false,
            attributions: []
        })
    }),
    layerWFS
],
view: new ol.View({
   center: [8561898.130561389, 3547876.863311305],
    zoom: 12
  })
 });

        </script>
```

**OPENLAYERS 2  and geoext**

```
 wfslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {

    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({

        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows',

  featureType: 'AMBALA_sma',
  featureNS: 'http://www.opengeospatial.net/',
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
  geometryName: 'the_geom',
  version: '1.0.0',
   outputFormat: "json",
        readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    })
});
 mapPanel.map.addLayers([layerWFS]);
```

Comment: try using the same URL for both requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few things that need checking:

1. Your Geoserver url looks odd.  See the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) on making a wfs request.  Try  `url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs`
2. check your featureNS. That also looks strange.  Is that what you set it as?
3. Is there any reason you are using version 1.1.0 in ol3 and 1.0.0 in ol2

Comment: i have changed url, featurens and version still layer is not displaying  wfslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
           
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',
     
      featureType: 'AMBALA_sma',
      featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/cite',
      srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
      geometryName: 'the_geom',
      version: '1.1.0
        })
    });

Comment: i have changed  featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite", then it is displaying